# Python Bokeh Title and Toolbar are not rendered

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh, dynamically-generated

I have written a [python class that is capable of live plotting data in different graphs](https://github.com/ticktronaut/dynamic_live_plot/blob/master/bokeh/bokeh_live_plot.py). It is based on [python bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/). Basically it is an abstraction of embedding bokeh server as a library and it is capable to dynamically add and remove figures and line glyphs during runtime. To make this happen in a non-blocking manner the main class extends *multithreading.Thread*. All codes can be found [here](https://github.com/ticktronaut/dynamic_live_plot).

An issue I encountered is that figures are not always rendered correctly. Often **Title and Toobar of the figures are not rendered**, as shown here (click on it to have a larger view on the gif):

[image: showcase of BokehLivePlot class]

Following javascript Error is thrown in the debug console of the browser (google chrome):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw_legend' of undefined

To add figures during runtim I am using the code bellow, where *fig* is a dictionary, which contains all figure objects in my projects and *cds* is a dictionary of all corresponding ColumnDataSource objects:

```
        if not fig_name in fig:
            print('add fig ' + fig_name)
            # create plot
            TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset, save, tap, hover"
            fig[fig_name]=figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=280, tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='right', logo=None, title=(fig_name), name=str(fig_name))
            cds[fig_name]=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=np.array([])), name=(fig_name+'_cds'))
            plt_col=doc.get_model_by_name('plt_ui_col').children
            plt_col.append( fig[fig_name] )
```

Is this a bug of bokeh?

Am I missing something? (Maybe the creation of some classes, that the figures depend on?)

I am using python3.6 and bokeh 0.12.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7497 I'd suggest you add any detailed information you can there.

Comment: I posted all information on github, thank you for the hint:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7497